# chrome extension: sharing an object between content scripts and background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that uses jQuery/Zepto in the content script. Now, the extension is meant to run on every website, which means a copy of jQuery/Zepto is loaded on each tab the user opens.

Is there a way to share the jQuery/Zepto object between the various content scripts?

I know content scripts can communicate with the background script. I was hoping to be able to let the background script have access to the jQuery object and return a reference to it, to each of the content scripts. But I realized only JSON messages can be passed between content and background scripts.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: No, you cannot share direct function references between content scripts. (duplicate question: [How to transfer data between the content scripts of two different tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597416/how-to-transfer-data-between-the-content-scripts-of-two-different-tabs)).

Comment: Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Btw, a question - I thought yesterday that getting jQuery included in every page might not actually be a problem, because unlike the actual resources of a webpage this doesn't have to be downloaded. Given that the average size of a webpage is approaching 1MB (as I read online), the increase in the memory consumption should not be much of a problem I reasoned. Does that seem to make sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Content scripts in different tabs do not have access to each other's JavaScript objects either.

Chrome supports communication between content scripts and/or the background page via [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) + [`.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage). Because all messages are JSON-serialized, JavaScript object cannot be "leaked" to other contexts in this way.

So: No, you cannot share objects such as jQuery with (content scripts in) other tabs.

Answer (score 1):

[Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) of [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) ensure content scripts can communicate among themselves

**Ex:**

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js","myscript1.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

A [Individual DOM Environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) where content scripts `["myscript.js","myscript1.js"]`  injected ensures `myscript1.js` have access to all contents *(Functions,Variables)* of `myscript.js`, but this stops from two [Individual DOM Environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication)'s being communicating.

Having said that, What Limitation\requirement you see in [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) which calls for requirement where **[message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)** needs [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) to access [DOM of injected pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication)?

Please Elaborate